# return value of a function is not shown in console (javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, console, return

I read all the previous and similar topics and I didnt get my answer
The problem is that the function "rockPaperScissors" doesn't return anything in the close despite the fact that I have put return messages inside for different conditions,
Thanks in advance ,
what is the problem and solution and what have I done wrong?

```js
let playerScore = 0;
      let computerScore = 0;
        
        let pcChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
      if (pcChoice === 1) {
        pcChoice = "rock";
      } else if (pcChoice === 2) {
        pcChoice = "paper";
      } else {
        pcChoice = "scissors";
      }

      let userInput = prompt("Rock ?\nPaper?\nScissors?")
      userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
      let errorMessage = "You have put a wrong input"
      if (! ((userInput === "rock") || (userInput === "paper") || (userInput === "scissors"))) {
        alert(errorMessage);
      } else {
        rockPaperScissors(userInput, pcChoice);
        console.log("Userscore is " + playerScore + "and Computerscore is " + computerScore);
       
      };


    if (playerScore > computerScore) {
      console.log("You are the winner");
    } else if (computerScore > playerScore) {
      console.log("Computer is the winner");
    } else { 
      console.log("It's a draw");
    }
      

    

      

      
      function rockPaperScissors(user, pc) {

        let winningMessage = "You Won!";
        let drawMessage = "it's a draw!";
        let losingMessage = " You lost!";
        if (user === "rock" & pc === "scissors") {

            playerScore++;
            return `You won! ${user} beats ${pc}`;
            
        } else if (user === "paper" & pc === "rock") {
          playerScore++;
          return `You won! ${user} beats ${pc}`;
          
        } else if (user === "scissors" & pc === "paper") {
          playerScore++;
          return `You won! ${user} beats ${pc}`;
          
        } else if (user === pc) {

          return drawMessage;
            
        } else {
            computerScore++;
            return `You won! ${pc} beats ${user}`;
        }

      }
```

Comment: You are ignoring the return value of `rockPaperScissors()`. What code do you expect to be responsible for showing the return value in the console?

Comment: thank you so much taking the time to answer ,
So just calling the function `rockPaperScissors(userInput, pcChoice)` is not enough ?
I supposed just calling it , should print the return in the console , 
It seems that my assumptions are incorrect regarding the return value of a function,
Could you please educate me on this point? how should I write the code from now on to print the return value of a function in the console?
`console.log()` ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Ivar , 
I think I have solved it , it's working , but I dont know if this was the best approach ,
I just added `console.log()` before the function ,
like this :   `console.log(rockPaperScissors(userInput, pcChoice));`

Comment: Your solution is fine. Alternatively you could use an intermediate variable such as `let result = rockPaperScissors(userInput, pcChoice); console.log(result);`, but that isn't really necessary here. Your `rockPaperScissors()` function isn't any different from other functions such as the `Math.floor()` you are using. Just calling `Math.floor()` without storing anything will just ignore the return value. You need to assign it to a variable as you do with `pcChoice` to be able to use the result.

Comment: Hi again @Ivar ,
Thanks for your previous comment , I have another question regarding the return value and I need your answer please, 
First , I didnt quite understand this part of your reply , could you elaborate it more using an example please?
" Your rockPaperScissors() function isn't any different from other functions such as the Math.floor() you are using. Just calling Math.floor() without storing anything will just ignore the return value. You need to assign it to a variable as you do with pcChoice to be able to use the result"

Comment: @Ivar,
second, the other day I was playing around a bit with the code , and I found a strange behavior from the function which I'd like to know your explanation please?

in your first comment you said " You are ignoring the return value of rockPaperScissors(). What code do you expect to be responsible for showing the return value in the console?" 
but why when I just use the `rockPaperScissors(rock, scissors)` manually in the console and call the function without `console.log()` command , I can see the result ?

Comment: ....continue
@Ivar

while when I was using that in the real code that I wrote `rockPaperScissors(userInput, pcChoice)` , it didnt print anything and that made me to come here and post my question?